# Callback function on custom $resource action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added a custom action to a $resource:

```
var myResource = $resource('some/url/:someParam',
   {
      someParam: '@someParam'
   },
   {
      update: {
         method: 'PUT'
      }
   });
```

I am attempting to have a function run on completion. According to Angular's documentation, I'd do it in the following way:

> **non-GET "class" actions:** Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])

Yet the following never invokes the success function even though the request is successful:

```
 myResource.update({ someParam: 'a value' }, { myPostData: 'goes here' }, function(a,b) {
    // this function never gets invoked
 });
```

The documentation also says this:

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.

But this doesn't work either:

```
 myResource.update({ someParam: 'a value' }, { myPostData: 'goes here' }).$promise.then(function() {
    // do stuff
 });
```

Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error you are getting ? or try instead of `$promise` direct use `.then` function

Comment: From the documentation, have you tried `,{success: { /*function here*/}}`?